# Arelle automate small procedure to trasfer data to Excel by using Python

Tags: python, excel, copy, xbrl, arelle

If we do these simple steps we will use [Arelle](http://arelle.org/) to fetch data from the SEC EDGAR database into the Arelle program.

The steps are:

1. Open Arelle and click the Open web file  which is an icon-button on the left top of the Arelle screen.
2. A box called Enter URL pops up. Please provide a URL that contains an XBRL Instance from the [Security and Exchange Commission](http://www.sec.gov/index.htm) (you can [take this URL for example](http://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1009672/000095012311018736/crr-20101231.xml)) and click OK.
3. When Arelle finished downloading (it takes ~10sec) please click the scale button which has an icon-button of a scale sketching second from the end on top left of the Arelle screen.

Now here is the simple procedure i want to Automate in Arelle with Python:

1. There is a tab in Arelle called `Fact Table` which has some items that can expand by clicking the plus sign next to them into a tree.
2. **Without** opening any of them if you `right click` one of them for example `0110 - Statement - Consolidated Balance Sheets` which is the second item you can go `Copy to clipboard` and then click `Table`.
3. Now please go to `Excel` and choose `Cell A1` and paste the data by pushing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> **+** <kbd>V</kbd>

*SUMMARY:* All i want is to do this in Python automatically.

Thank you for your attention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Arelle](http://arelle.org/) provide a Python API that you can find [here](http://arelle.org/documentation/api/) with the documentation [here](http://arelle.readthedocs.org/en/latest/).

This API will allow you to automate your process by scripting actions, this removes the necessity to automate working with the GUI itself which would be cumbersome.